# How to make a HEAD request in c++ using libevent

Tags: c++, http, networking

I want to use the [Libevent Library](https://github.com/libevent/libevent) to make an HTTP `HEAD` request to a website just to get its status code.

How would I go about doing that?

I've been looking at this: https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/sample/https-client.c, but I don't know how to make a `HEAD` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://libevent.org/doc/http_8h.html#a88c4f63045dc6567f8220d6d37426924), you can use `EVHTTP_REQ_HEAD` instead of `EVHTTP_REQ_GET` when calling `evhttp_make_request()`.